# How to get parent object's property inside child class in php?

Tags: php, oop, parent-child

Please observe that it's been a while since I tried my hand at php and oop...

I wish to aid my partner in keeping track of our massive Magic: The Gathering card collection.
In Magic, generally, cards are released in expansion blocks. Within a block there are three expansions. The first expansion has the same name, symbol etc as the whole block, they are really more or less the same but I wish to make a difference between the Block and the Expansion within my code.

At the same time I'd like to avoid to enter the same information twice when adding the first expansion to the block;

```
$block = new Block('Innistrad', 'isd', '130927');
$exp = $block->addExpansion(new Expansion('Innistrad', 'isd', '130927')); // not DRY!
$firstExp = $block->addExpansion(new Expansion('Innistrad')); // This is more DRY, only name is needed
```

All expansions have the same rotation date as the block. This I managed to set in the addExpansion(Expansion $exp) method;

```
$exp->rotationDate = $this->rotationDate;
```

Somehow I'd like to add a condition in the Expansion constructor to compare the expansion name to the block name. If they are equal, expansion symbol is the same as block symbol, else expansion symbol is set in the constructor method. I've tried to use `$block =  get_parent_class($this);` and then `$this->name == $block->name` as condition but (of course?) this did not work as expected and expansion symbol "input" is null? Instead of "isd.png" symbol is ".png".

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in - on line 178
Expansion Object
(
    [name:protected] => Innistrad
    [symbol:protected] => .png
    [rotationDate] => 130927
)
```

"Complete" code with classes and comments where I've tried and failed...

```
// BLOCK
class Block {
    protected static $imgType = '.png';
    protected $name;
    protected $symbol;

    public function __construct($name, $symbol, $rotationDate) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->symbol = $symbol.self::$imgType;
        $this->rotationDate = $rotationDate;
    }

    public function addExpansion(Expansion $exp) {
        $exp->rotationDate = $this->rotationDate;
        return $exp;
    }
}

// EXPANSION
class Expansion extends Block {
    public function __construct($name, $symbol = null) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $block = get_parent_class($this); // this is what I tried, the principle of what I try to achieve
        if ($this->name == $block->name) {
        // if the instantiated child object has the same name as the parent object, "adopt" the parent object's properties
            $this->symbol = $block->symbol;
        }
        else {
            $this->symbol = $symbol.parent::$imgType;
        }
    }
}
$block = new Block('Innistrad', 'isd', '130927');
$exp = $block->addExpansion(new Expansion('Innistrad'));
print_r($exp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're abusing the child - parent thing here. If u create an `Expansion` there is only one object, the `Expansion` it self. Extending a parent class does not mean an `instance`of the parent will be created, it just makes that the child class inherits all functionality of the parent class.
You should change your `addExpansion` method and the construct your `Expansion` to something like this :

```
public function addExpansion(Expansion $exp) {
    $exp->setParentBlock($this);
    $exp->rotationDate = $this->rotationDate;
    return $exp;
}
```

---

```
class Expansion extends Block {
    private $parent = null;

    public function setParentBlock(Block $b) {
      $this->parent = $b;
    }
    public function __construct($name, $symbol = null) {
        $this->name = $name;
        //create getName() because u can't access protected outside the class
        if ($this->parent != null && $this->name == $parent->getName()) {
        // if the instantiated child object has the same name as the parent object, "adopt" the parent object's properties
            $this->symbol = $block->symbol;
        }
        else {
            $this->symbol = $symbol.parent::$imgType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspected there was something wrong with my use of parent-child relations. I tried the above suggestion but never got the desired result of Expansion $symbol to equal Block $symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've accidentally solved my problem. Instead of stating the if condition in the Expansion constructor I put it in the addExpansion() method in the Block class. This gives the desired result of "adopted" property values but I'm unsure whether it is a proper solution.

```
// BLOCK
class Block {
    protected static $imgType = '.png';
    protected $name;
    protected $symbol;
    protected $rotationDate;

    public function __construct($name, $symbol, $rotationDate) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->symbol = $symbol.self::$imgType;
        $this->rotationDate = $rotationDate;
    }

    public function addExpansion(Expansion $exp) {
        $exp->rotationDate = $this->rotationDate;
        if ($exp->name == $this->name) { // if Expansion name equals Block name
            $exp->symbol = $this->symbol; // use Block symbol as Expansion symbol
        }
        return $exp;
    }
}

// EXPANSION
class Expansion extends Block {
    public function __construct($name, $symbol = null) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->symbol = $symbol.parent::$imgType;
    }
}
$block = new Block('Innistrad', 'isd_exp_symbol', '20130927');
$exp = $block->addExpansion(new Expansion('Innistrad'));
print_r($exp);
```

Returns:

```
Expansion Object
(
    [name:protected] => Innistrad
    [symbol:protected] => isd_exp_symbol.png
    [rotationDate:protected] => 20130927
)
```

Comment: U did it the other way arround. I advice you to store the expansions in an array so u can keep track of them more easily

Comment: Thank you, will do. =) This is a (very) simplified version of my code to highlight and focus on the former(?) problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering because I think there's a problem with @DarkBee's solution, but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so instead I'll offer a complete solution (the problem is that $this->parent will always be null in the constructor of Expansion, because setParentBlock isn't called until after construction).

I'm sceptical that you need the Expansion class to extend the Block class, but I've left that in anyway - it works just as well (better, IMO) if you comment out "extends Block". Any questions, feel free to ask.

```
// BLOCK
class Block {
    protected static $imgType = '.png';
    protected $name;
    protected $symbol;
    protected $expansions = array();

    public function __construct($name, $symbol, $rotationDate) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->symbol = $symbol.self::$imgType;
        $this->rotationDate = $rotationDate;
    }

    public function addExpansion($name, $symbol = null) {
        // We only have room for 3 expansions.
        if (count($this->expansions) >= 3) return null;

        // If the expansion to be created and added to this block has the
        // same name as this block, or if no symbol is supplied,
        // then "adopt" this block's symbol. 
        $symbol = ($name == $this->name || $symbol === null)
          ? $this->symbol
          : $symbol.self::$imgType;

        $exp = new Expansion($name, $symbol, $this->rotationDate);
        $this->expansions[] = $exp;

        return $exp;
    }
}

// EXPANSION
class Expansion extends Block {
    public function __construct($name, $symbolWithType, $rotationDate) {
        $this->name         = $name;
        $this->symbol       = $symbolWithType;
        $this->rotationDate = $rotationDate;
    }
}

$block = new Block('Innistrad', 'isd', '130927');
$exp = $block->addExpansion('Innistrad');
print_r($exp);
```